# port forwarding with socks over proxy

Tags: ssh, socks

I am trying to browse a wiki that runs on a server inside one domain from another domain.
The wiki is accessible only on the LAN, but I need to browse it from another LAN to which I connect with an SSH tunnel ...

Here is my setup and the steps I did so far:

`~.ssh/confing` on `wikihost`:

```
Host gateway
  User kisteuser
  Port 443
  Hostname gateway.companydomain.com
  ProxyCommand /home/myuser/bin/ssh-https-tunnel %h %p
  # ssh-https-tunnel:
  # http://ttcplinux.sourceforge.net/tools/stunnel
  Protocol 2
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key_dsa
  LocalForward 11069 localhost:11069

Host server1
  User kisteuser
  Hostname localhost
  Port 11069
  LocalForward 8022 server1:22
  LocalForward 17001 server1:7100
  LocalForward 8080 www-proxy:3128
  RemoteForward 11069 localhost:22
```

from `wikihost`

```
myuser@wikihost: ssh -XC -t gateway.companydomain.com ssh -L11069:localhost:22 server1
```

on another terminal:

```
ssh gateway.companydomain.com
```

Now, on my companydomain I would like to start firefox and browse the wiki on `wikihost`.
I did:

```
kisteuser@kiste.companydomain.com ~ $ ssh gateway
Have a lot of fun...
kisteuser@gateway ~ $ ssh -D 8383 localhost
user@localhost's password: 
user@wikiserver:~>
```

My `.ssh/config` on that side looks like that:

```
host server1
    localforward 11069 localhost:11069

host localhost
    user myuser
    port 11069

host wikiserver
    forwardagent yes
    user myuser
    port 11069
    hostname localhost
```

Now, I started firefox on the server called `gateway`, and edited the proxy settings to use SOCKSv5, specifying that the proxy should be `gateway` and use the port 8383...

```
kisteuser@gateway ~ $ LANG=C firefox -P --no-remote
```

And, now I get the following error popping in the Terminal of `wikiserver`:

```
myuser@wikiserver:~> channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

Confused? Me too ...

Please help me understand how to properly build the tunnels and browse the wiki over SOCKS protocol.

#### update:

I managed to browse the wiki on wikiserver with the following changes:

```
host wikiserver
    forwardagent yes
    user myuser
    port 11069
    hostname localhost 
    localforward 8339 localhost:8443
```

Now when I ssh `gateway` I launch Firefox and go to localhost:8339 and I hit the start page of the wiki, which is served on Port 8443.

Now I ask myself is SOCKS really needed? Can someone elaborate on that ?

Comment: so, to clarify, kiste.companydomain.com is on one LAN, and hosts 'gateway' and 'wikiserver' are on another LAN?  and gateway and wikiserver are on the same LAN?

Comment: @TimKennedy: kiste.companydomain.com and gateway are on one LAN, wikiserver are on another LAN...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set up SOCKS the way you want, you need to run the `ssh -D 8383` command **on** the machine where you want to run your browser, and make it connect **to** a machine that has access to the wiki. You should also use `localhost:8383` as the proxy address, because
`ssh -D` by default listens only on `localhost` as the man page says:

> By default, the local port is bound in accordance with the
>   GatewayPorts setting.  However, an explicit bind_address may be used
>   to bind the connection to a specific address

So, if `gateway` has access to `wikihost`, but you want to run your browser on `kiste`, you should run firefox on `kiste`, configure it with "localhost:8383" as SOCKS proxy, and also run `ssh -D 8383 gateway` from `kiste`.

A few other notes to keep in mind:

Try running all the ssh commands with `-v`. This will show you all the forwards that are being requested and you'll be able to see which one exactly is failing.

I would also recommend taking out the tunnels that you do not really need, just to make the situation less confusing.

The error message that you are seeing is triggered when something tries to connect to one end of a **static** SSH tunnel (one you create with `-L` or `-R`) but SSH is unable to connect to the other end of the tunnel.